# Activator.CreateInstance needs another object to be instantiated

Tags: c#

I am instantiating my objects with the classical

```
object myObject = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
```

code and if works fine.
The thing is that, now, Id like to instantiate an object and in its constructor, there is a reference to another object.
So if I just do the code above, I got a `NullReferenceException` exception :

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I tried to instantiate the concerned object (with Activator.CreateInstance) but I got the same exception...
I feel like instantiating the problematic object before my 2nd CreateInstance call is not enough. What should I do ?

EDIT : here's the code of the problem

```
//A regionManager in needed by MainView as far as I understand the Exception's details
var regionManager = Assembly.LoadFrom("RegionView.dll");
Type rmType = regionManager.GetType("Framework.Hmi.RegionManager");
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(rmType);
//This works !

var shellViewLibrary = Assembly.LoadFrom("ShellView.dll");
Type svType = shellViewLibrary.GetType("Framework.ShellView.MainView");
object objjj = Activator.CreateInstance(svType);
```

The last line fails and the error is a `NullReferenceException` with the details :

```
at Hmi.RegionManager.get_RegionFactory()
at Hmi.RegionManager.CreateRegion(DependencyObject element)
at Hmi.RegionManager.OnSetRegionNameCallback(DependencyObject element, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
[...]
```

I call c/c the 30/40 other error lines but I don't think it is that usefull...

Comment: It's hard to say exactly what's going on - we've no idea where the exception is being thrown, etc. Please provide a short but complete program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: svType could be null ... ?
(the stack seems to indicate that's not your problem, but never know ^^)

Comment: Can't you debug get_RegionFactory() to see where the problem is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say your constructor references another object, do you mean you should be passing it to the constructor as a parameter? If so, then there is an overload for `Activator.CreateInstance` that allows you to specify the parameter values. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx) for details, but basically, you add them after the type.

Comment: There is a constructor without parameters, and that's the one I'm trying to call ! So I think that the "another object" is used in the constructor code